# Openshift: memory limit and gear stop

Tags: openshift

The command `oo-cgroup-read memory.failcnt` shows positive number after `gear stop`, `gear start`. Does 'gear stop' mean that memory will be cleaned?

My application shows 84946 with `oo-cgroup-read memory.failcnt` even after pushing new commit to the server. I do not know the reason because before the memory was enough.

Answer (score 1):

That number is not cleared automatically, try keeping track of it and see if it is going up as your application runs.  That is a good indication that your application needs to either run on a larger gear, or you have some kind of memory leak.  Depending on how much memory your application goes over your limit, your application may get OOM Killed (Out of Memory) and not restart automatically, either way, it's a good time to maybe do some application memory profiling, or try installing New Relic to see how much memory you are using and where it might be leaky.

Comment: I opened up three different browsers and the number still the same. 
It seems that the 'groving' hapened after users actions.

Comment: That is a possibility, just opening the site may not do it, you probably have to interact with it and see what actions are causing the issue.